# Sum over dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `stat` of size `3 x 5` (three variables `a`, `b` and `c` with five data points each) and get the following output using `print(stat)`:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,{
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 3, 0, 0): {'a': 18, 'b': 82, 'c': 30}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 4, 0, 0): {'a': 14, 'b': 10, 'c': 24}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 5, 0, 0): {'a': 14, 'b': 61, 'c': 54}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 0, 0): {'a': 32, 'b': 10, 'c': 81}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 7, 0, 0): {'a': 28, 'b': 12, 'c': 60}
})
```

I also have a list `art` where the variables are stored: `art = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

At the moment I calculate the sum by doing this:

```
j=0
for key in stat:
    for k in range(5):
        data[k][j] = stat[key][art[k]]
    j=j+1

sum_per_var = np.sum(data, axis=1)
```

And get:

```
sum_per_var = [ 106.  175.  249.]
```

But this approach seems really clumpy. Is there a cleaner way to compute the sum of the variables `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: What’s `data`? Do you need to use it afterwards? Are the values always integers?

Comment: `for k in range(5)` and `art[k]` will raise an `IndexError` exception. Is that code a copy and paste?

Comment: How come you get `sum_per_var = [ 106.  175.  249.]` with an `IndexError` being raised?

Comment: @ElisByberi I did not copy and paste the code. It is part of a larger project and I wanted to make my question as clear as possible. I should have posted a minimal working example of the code. Sorry for that. I just wanted to make the problem clear and visible.

Comment: @Samuel So, you do not get an `IndexError` exception?

Comment: @ElisByberi No, I don't get that error.

Comment: @Samuel You are lucky!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain Python, you could use a list comprehension of `sum`s with generator comprehension:

```
[sum(d[key] for d in stat.values()) for key in art]
```

As an example:

```
import datetime
stat = {
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 3, 0, 0): {'a': 18, 'b': 82, 'c': 30}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 4, 0, 0): {'a': 14, 'b': 10, 'c': 24}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 5, 0, 0): {'a': 14, 'b': 61, 'c': 54}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 0, 0): {'a': 32, 'b': 10, 'c': 81}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 7, 0, 0): {'a': 28, 'b': 12, 'c': 60}
}
art = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[sum(d[key] for d in stat.values()) for key in art]
# [106, 175, 249]
```

It might be easier and more concise with Pandas, though:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
stat = {
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 3, 0, 0): {'a': 18, 'b': 82, 'c': 30}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 4, 0, 0): {'a': 14, 'b': 10, 'c': 24}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 5, 0, 0): {'a': 14, 'b': 61, 'c': 54}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 0, 0): {'a': 32, 'b': 10, 'c': 81}, 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 7, 0, 0): {'a': 28, 'b': 12, 'c': 60}
}
pd.DataFrame(stat).T
#              a   b   c
# 2017-11-03  18  82  30
# 2017-11-04  14  10  24
# 2017-11-05  14  61  54
# 2017-11-06  32  10  81
# 2017-11-07  28  12  60
pd.DataFrame(stat).T.sum()
# a    106
# b    175
# c    249
```

Comment: Great! I really like the solution with `pandas`.  Thank you!